# Loading asynchronous data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I'm getting a `Cannot read property of undefined` error when calling a function, however the data is being displayed correctly.

According to what I've read so far, that's because of asynchronous load of data made by AngularJS and that I should use promises to avoid that.

I've searched online and Angular's documentation but I didn't understand how to use it.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
.factory('Test', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('data.json');
}])

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Test', function($scope, Test) {

Test.get(function (data) {
  $scope.myData = data;
});

$scope.myFunction = function() {
  var min = $scope.myData.min;
  var max = $scope.myData.max;
  var diff = max - min;
  return diff;
}

}])
```

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3AK70uVbNSdhAIIfdkHb?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `$scope.myData.min` until `$scope.myData` is populated, which as you correctly said is asynchronous so can take a moment. The simplest solution is in this case just wrap your code into if-block:

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
  if ($scope.myData) {
    var min = $scope.myData.min;
    var max = $scope.myData.max;
    var diff = max - min;
    return diff;
  }
}
```

`myFunction` is going to be checked in every digest cycle so once $scope.myData is available it the function will evaluate and return `diff` properly.

**However**, much better approach would be to work with a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) object returned by resource. In this case you could do something like this:

```
function myFunction(myData) {
  var min = myData.min;
  var max = myData.max;
  var diff = max - min;
  return diff;
}

Test.get().$promise.then(myFunction).then(function(data) {
  $scope.myData = data;
});
```

and in HTML use `myData` without a function:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{myData}}
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2SSk2lChkbvm5ffbHF2n?p=preview

Comment: I was just thinking: what if I'd want to pass a value to the function (e.g. `{{myData(2)}}` where `2` would be `min`. Then, I wouldn't be able to use your second approach, right?

Comment: Then you wouldn't be able to use it, yes. However, I wouldn't recommend using functions like this, the function is going to be called many times, with possible performance issues. It's better to set scope property and use it inside of myFunction.

Comment: I see. But let's say I'd like something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/9qv6cXs1RaOOaxhJ3U1X?p=preview - then, is there a better way than using a function like this?

Comment: Actually, I made some changes to the code above (http://plnkr.co/edit/Bi17ENfKoAelqgihEeQs?p=preview) but I wonder if it's a good practice to put calculations right into the HTML instead of writing a function for it.

Comment: Yes, in this case with simple calculation it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `$scope.myData = {}`

e.g. for your code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Test', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('data.json');
}])

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Test', function($scope, Test) {
  $scope.myData = {}  // <--- That's what I have defined
  Test.get(function (data) {
      $scope.myData = data;
  });

  $scope.myFunction = function() {
      var min = $scope.myData.min;
    var max = $scope.myData.max;
    var diff = max - min;
    return diff;
  }

}])
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine, maybe a little modification to avoid

> Cannot read property of undefined error

```
$scope.myData = Test.get();
```

Then u can have

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    var min = $scope.myData.min;
    var max = $scope.myData.max;
    var diff = max - min;
    return diff || 0;
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource